# Visualizing dataset into d3 contour by converting obervable to notebook to plain JS

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, observable, contour

I have a data set that needs to be visualized using the d3 contour chart from below link
https://observablehq.com/@d3/contours

The CSV file is as follows.

```
x,y,z
3100,200,290.5
3100,190,297.4
3100,180,298.4
3100,170,302.4
3100,160,314.5
3100,150,342.9
3100,140,393.1
3100,130,385.8
3100,120,463.6
3100,110,670.4
3000,200,288.5
3000,190,287.2
3000,180,295.3
3000,170,304.2
3000,160,315.4
3000,150,326.1
3000,140,363.5
3000,130,403.7
3000,120,484.8
3000,110,646.2
2900,200,280.9
2900,190,283.9
2900,180,286.8
2900,170,294.0
2900,160,302.2
2900,150,317.9
2900,140,349.9
2900,130,415.2
2900,120,525.4
2900,110,621.7
2800,200,278.3
2800,190,282.3
2800,180,285.1
2800,170,291.7
2800,160,298.9
2800,150,316.8
2800,140,350.4
2800,130,397.5
2800,120,458.7
2800,110,583.9
2700,200,277.6
2700,190,278.3
2700,180,284.4
2700,170,288.2
2700,160,292.7
2700,150,308.0
2700,140,327.6
2700,130,359.3
2700,120,440.3
2700,110,615.6
2600,200,277.2
2600,190,277.0
2600,180,280.0
2600,170,283.7
2600,160,294.6
2600,150,308.0
2600,140,325.9
2600,130,360.0
2600,120,421.6
2600,110,598.8
2500,200,273.9
2500,190,274.9
2500,180,278.7
2500,170,283.4
2500,160,291.8
2500,150,301.9
2500,140,319.7
2500,130,349.0
2500,120,414.6
2500,110,595.5
2400,200,273.4
2400,190,274.4
2400,180,277.7
2400,170,280.2
2400,160,285.4
2400,150,299.8
2400,140,314.6
2400,130,336.5
2400,120,387.4
2400,110,541.6
2300,200,273.4
2300,190,277.5
2300,180,274.6
2300,170,277.2
2300,160,284.5
2300,150,295.8
2300,140,307.7
2300,130,334.6
2300,120,380.1
2300,110,521.3
2200,200,270.5
2200,190,271.6
2200,180,273.3
2200,170,274.8
2200,160,282.5
2200,150,289.3
2200,140,302.1
2200,130,323.5
2200,120,368.5
2200,110,507.6
2100,200,270.5
2100,190,268.2
2100,180,269.0
2100,170,271.2
2100,160,277.6
2100,150,285.4
2100,140,299.0
2100,130,320.0
2100,120,366.1
2100,110,503.0
2000,200,271.7
2000,190,268.8
2000,180,268.5
2000,170,273.3
2000,160,278.7
2000,150,285.2
2000,140,295.3
2000,130,317.1
2000,120,361.5
2000,110,486.9
```

Column x and y are to be used for x-axis and y-axis.
Column Z are the values which are already computed, I guess these values needs to be used for threshold component.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: I want to use the above dataset shared for the chart

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Do you have any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, the sample from Observable does not help a lot since its data structure differs from yours.

Anyway, you can build contours by processing your data using the following algorithm (it's a lot of coding, but I can't suggest a better way):

1. Find the total range of Z values (min/max) and split it to a number of sub-ranges (< 200, 200 < 300, ..., 500 < 600, 600 <). Now you have a set of values [200,300,400,500,600] to build the contours for each of them
2. For each edge value, build its contour as following:

- Iterate through all Y coordinates

  - Iterate through all points with the same Y value, find the X coordinates of the points which Z value is close to the edge value, collect those points.
- Build contour by adding collected points one by one (the next one should be closest to the previous)

3. For each contour build an SVG path string 'M x1,y1 L x2,y2 L x3,y3 ... L xN,yN Z'
4. Draw paths one by one with <path d="M ... Z" fill="value-color" stroke="edge-color" />

Good luck :)

Comment: In point 1 the set of values [200,300...] are these the counts of numbers falling into the range? or threshold values?

Comment: Threshold values indeed

Comment: How do I compute the grid using the dataset? I have to arrive at the visualization as posted in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163395/3d-surface-charts-using-d3?noredirect=1#comment118717784_67163395 here